# applying function to a vector

Tags: r, quantlib

I have a set of dates (as.Date from RQuantLib) stored as a list or row in my_dates

I would like to select the first value for which this condition is true

```
businessDaysBetween("UnitedStates", TodayDate, my_dates)>10
```

where `TodayDate<-as.Date(format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d"), "%Y%m%d")` is today date.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `which` on the result of your `businessDaysBetween` call.

```
set.seed(21)
my_dates <- Sys.Date()+sample(50,10)
bizday_gt10 <- sapply(my_dates, businessDaysBetween,
                      calendar="UnitedStates", from=Sys.Date()) > 10
if(any(bizday_gt10)) {
  first_bizday_gt10 <- which(bizday_gt10)[1]
  my_dates[first_bizday_gt10]
} else {
  stop("no business days between today and today+10")
}
```

Note that you need to check that there's *at least* 1 `TRUE` observation in `bizday_gt10`, else `which` will return a zero-length vector.

Comment: this does not work, because businessDaysBetween does not like arrays, it only accepts single value: `businessDaysBetween("UnitedStates", TodayDate, calls_expiry)` produces `4` for `my_dates <-"2013-04-12" "2013-04-19" "2013-05-17" "2013-06-21" "2013-07-19" "2013-10-18" "2014-01-17" "2015-01-16"`

Comment: Possible strategy:  make a wrapper function, use sapply with this function and the data vector to get a vector of daysbetween, then use vector-friendly methods

Comment: @Sergey: you didn't mention that in your question and you didn't provide a reproducible example, so I had no idea that was the actual problem you were facing. Regardless, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Joshua and Paul. I am new to R, often it is hard even to describe the question in a correct R language. I combined both your answers and this is what I got: ` my_dates[sapply(as.Date(my_dates), businessDaysBetween, calendar="UnitedStates", from=Sys.Date()) > 1][1]`

Comment: @Sergey: that's why you should provide a reproducible example; that way the question is more evident.  Your combined answer is dangerous for the reason I note in my answer: it's possible that the logical comparison will have no `TRUE` values, in which case your subset of `my_dates` will be a zero-length vector... and you'll get `NA` if you try to subset it. Then you'll be back here asking another question about why it doesn't work. :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, will do it next time for sure!

Answer (score 0):

This can be very simple, if you want only the values or the first value.

A conditional statement applied to a vector results in a true/false vector

A true/false vector can be used as an index to a vector, and returns a shorter vector of the values where the condition is true.

Example: Initialize x to contain 10 random numbers. Is each one bigger than 0.7? Now return those that are bigger than 0.7. Then return the first one.

```
x = rnorm(10)
x
 [1] -0.96029244  0.41779224  0.08058894 -0.02026729 -0.65383370 -0.83572926
 [7]  0.92722221  0.49157700  0.88779718 -1.09073923
x>0.7
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
x[x>0.7]
[1] 0.9272222 0.8877972

first one...

x[x>0.7][1]
[1] 0.9272222
```

Comment: This does not work in my case: `> my_dates
[1] "2013-04-12" "2013-04-19" "2013-05-17" "2013-06-21" "2013-07-19" "2013-10-18" "2014-01-17" "2015-01-16"
> businessDaysBetween("UnitedStates", Sys.Date(), as.Date(my_dates))
[1] 4`. For some reason, this function returns only single value.

Comment: Thank you very much Joshua and Paul. I am new to R, often it is hard even to describe the question in a correct R language. I combined both your answers and this is what I got: ` my_dates[sapply(as.Date(my_dates), businessDaysBetween, calendar="UnitedStates", from=Sys.Date()) > 1][1]`

Comment: Try making a single argument function, by replacing the ... with your complete function call above:  myBizDays<-function(my_date){ businessDaysBetween(..., as.Date(my_date))} ... Then use sapply like this:  daysBetween = sapply(myBizDays, my_dates) ... Then daysBetweeen should be a vector of integers and the tricks in the answer above will work.

Comment: @Sergey I confess I don't often use sapply with additional parameters, and usually rewrite a complex function call with a wrapper so that there is only one argument.  If your single line works for you, great!